# In Directed-mapped cache, a problem in exercise!

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, cache

> 5.2 Caches are important to providing a high-performance memory hierarchy
>   to processors. Below is a list of 32-bit memory address references, given as word
>   addresses.
>
> 3, 180, 43, 2, 191, 88, 190, 14, 181, 44, 186, 253
>
> 5.2.1 For each of these references, identify the binary address, the tag,
>   and the index given a direct-mapped cache with 16 one-word blocks. Also list if each
>   reference is a hit or a miss, assuming the cache is initially empty.
>
> 5.2.2 For each of these references, identify the binary address, the tag,
>   and the index given a direct-mapped cache with two-word blocks and a total size of 8
>   blocks. Also list if each reference is a hit or a miss, assuming the cache is initially empty.

It is easy to answer this question, just calculate the tag, index, and offset, then we  are done. For examples, we are given in 5.2.1 a directed-mapped cache with 16 one-word blocks, therefore we have index n=4, and tag is 32 - (4+0+2)=26, but in the solution sheet [here](https://www.studocu.com/tw/document/feng-chia-university/information-engineering-and-computer-science/other/eetopcn-mkcomputerorganizationanddesign5theditionsep2013-answers/1974049/view) (see the figure for a solution instead of taken several minutes to see the answer in the link), tag: 32 - 4 = 28! how to deal with this problem? It is really confusing! in the book, it says: tag = 32 - (n + m +2), where n is the index and m is the number of word in one block.

Could someone explains to me whether the solution sheet made a mistake or me!

Here is the solution in figure:
[image]

Here is a figure taken from the book in the page the explains how to find the tag:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

word address 3 means 12~16(1100~1111) for byte address so [1:0] should be an offset bit.
Tag = 32 -(index+offset) = 32 - 4 - 2 = 26